# Как собрать .exe файл для Mac OS , используя pycharm и windows 11

Tags: python, pycharm, macos, exe

У меня есть мини-проект с визуализацией некоторых математических объектов с помощью всем известным библиотекам matplotlib и networkx. В проекте лишь один .py файлик, который принимает на вход некоторые данные, обрабатывает их и визуализирует.
Проблем со сборкой однофайлового .exe не возникает,на windows 10-11 файл открывается и работает без особых проблем, однако при попытке открыть файл на Mac OS возникают проблемы. (Возможно, из-за другой архитектуры процессора, АRM вместо привычной x86 для интела). И мне нужно найти способ, который поможет собрать проект в Pycharm для Mac OS, используя при этом windows 11. Есть ли какие-то решения для этого?

p.s. Собираю в .exe файл с помощью библиотеки pyinstaller одной командой:
pyinstaller --onefile main.py

Comment: посмотрите на [`py2app`](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), возможно, подойдет.. или в сторону `mkfs.hfsplus` можно посмотреть [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286419/how-to-build-a-dmg-mac-os-x-file-on-a-non-mac-platform)

Comment: Не хотите поставить Wine на мак?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , как один из вариантов, но Мака под рукой нет. Иначе я бы собрал бы проект аналогичной командой на нем, ведь Pyinstaller - кроссплатформенная библиотека.